# Android device hardware buttons always "on"

Tags: android, hardware

There are 3, sometimes 4, hardware buttons on all the Android devices. I'd like the backlight for these buttons to be always "on", for as long as my application executes in the foreground. Even though I'm for some reason pretty sure that Android doesn't support this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html), the `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` “ensures that the screen and keyboard are on at full brightness.” I believe this includes the soft buttons.

Comment: Wow, awesome, that along with ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP is exactly what I needed. This is just brilliant, thank you so much!